# How to install OpenCV in Docker (CentOs)?

Tags: python, linux, docker, opencv, anaconda

I am trying to install OpenCV in a docker container (CentOS).

I tried installing python first and then tried `yum install opencv-contrib` but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me out as to how to install OpenCV in Docker (CentOS)?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: Please include a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

To install OpenCV use the command: sudo yum install opencv opencv-devel opencv-python
And when the installation is completed use the command to verify: pkg-config --modversion opencv